# SendKey string + enter at the same time

Tags: vba, sendkeys

Is it possible to send a string and an enter with `SendKeys`?

I tried this:

```
Application.SendKeys "String? {ENTER}"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Application.SendKeys "String?~"`

Comment: I've never seen anybody do this. Why do you need to do it together?

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine submitting each key seperately, at least that is how i have done it when i have used send keys recently;

```
Application.SendKeys "MyString"
Application.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using excel 2013 and this works for me

Sendkeys "12345" & "{ENTER}"

It will output the 12345 and do a carriage return..
Makes the code a little cleaner to have all the text on one line for putty purposes

Answer (score 0):

Previously I have succesfully used a variation of the code below. My code did not the Application. code. This should concatenate the two strings.

```
Application.Sendkeys "myString" + "{ENTER}"
```

Tested

```
SendKeys "myString" + "{ENTER}"
```

on Excel 2016 and it does work.